# Django. self.file.path does not include upload_to subdirectory

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get some information from a file before the Model is saved to the database.
So basically what i'm doing it is overwriting method save like follow:

```
class Media(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='audio/')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
             print self.file.path
        super(Media, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But when I print attribute self.file.path is does not include "audio/" subdirectory.
Instead of this '/Users/me/Dropbox/Public/music/audio/myfile.ext'

I'm getting 
'/Users/me/Dropbox/Public/music/myfile.ext'

The file is located where it suppose to be. In 
 '/Users/me/Dropbox/Public/music/audio/myfile.ext'

My

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/me/Dropbox/Public/music'
```

What I've missed?

**UPDATE:**
Looks like it add 'audio/' to the path after it save the model.

Comment: What do you see if you print the following in the if statement: `print self.file.field.get_directory_name()`?